# Book about kids with mental powers and aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, powers

I am looking to find the name of a book I read a few years ago, but cannot remember.

I have some information about the book from memory but after an hour searching google I am none the wiser.

A few bits of info

- I am SURE the title starts with an I
- The image on the front cover is like a dipyramid prism, possibly with a bird.
- Plot info : kids with psychic/mental powers, an alien council of multiple races/powers that are some sort of universal guardians or federation of planets

Comment: Do you know if the book was recently released when you read it?

Comment: i read it about 10 years ago, so not sure really

Comment: What's "the image in the from"?  You mean the front cover?

Comment: sorry yes cjm, awful bit of typing there. should learn to proof read before I post

Comment: @Nick Click 'edit' below your question to make updates to it.

Answer (score 10):

[*Intervention*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0065L9H9I) by Julian May.
It's the novel linking the first series (*Saga of Pliocene Exiles*) and the second series (*Galactic Milieu*).

It shows the childhood of the Remillard family who are all powerful psychics and the key players in both series. Earth is watched over by four alien races, who are debating whether or not to allow humans to join their interstellar society.

[image]

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44937/book-series-about-time-travel-from-future-to-distant-past-psychic-powers about the "Saga of Pliocene Exile" series

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like Chocky, by Jon Wyndham.

Comment: That's only 1 kid and 1 alien and it doesn't start with I.

Comment: Please provide details for why you think this story fits the description.