# Book series about time travel from future to distant past, psychic powers?

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, aliens, psychic

Please help me identify this book series:

In the future, humanity has started to develop psychic powers by encouraging breeding of genetic traits. Humans find a way to travel back to a specific time in the past, and everyone is really excited. Then, the travelers discover that time (possibly different place as well?) is already ruled by aliens, and the humans get enslaved.

The aliens and humans have different kinds of psychic powers, like farseers, psychokinetic powers, mind readers, and so on, and are very powerful. There is one human whose psychic abilities were limited in the future, but in the past he becomes one of the most powerful psychics.

There is a big war pitting all the psychics against each other.

The aliens might be some sort of proto-humans. I vaguely remember them looking like humans, but bigger. Please help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Julian May, [*Saga of Pliocene Exile*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile) which is four books
:

```
The Many Colored Land,   
The Golden Torc,   
The Nonborn King,   
The Adversary.
```

> The time-travelers arrive to discover the Pliocene is already inhabited by a dimorphic race of aliens ('exotics'), the Tanu and the Firvulag.

It was Aiken Drum, the non-born, who was the latent Paramount Grandmaster. May also wrote several other novels in this universe, culminating in the tale of Jack the Bodiless and Diamond Mask.